# Problem regarding cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with the following cumulative distribution function:

> $$F(x)= 
> \begin{cases}
> 0 & \quad x<0\\
> x^2 & \quad 0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}\\
> \frac{3}{4} & \quad \frac{1}{2}\leq x<1\\
> 1 &\quad x\geq1.
> \end{cases}$$

Then what is the value of $P(\frac{1}{4}<X<1).$

I am trying to solve this problem as:

> $P(\frac{1}{4}<X<1)=P(\frac{1}{4}<X\leq1)$, since for continuous random variable probability at a point is always zero.
>   Thus $P(\frac{1}{4}<X<1)=P(\frac{1}{4}<X\leq1)=F(1)-F(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{15}{16}=0.9375$. But the answer didn't match. Answer is 0.68. So where did i wrong. Any suggestion or solution regarding this should be highly appreciated.

Comment: Who told you the CDF is continuous at $x=1$? More care, please...

Comment: @Did I guess it as the range of the random variable $X$ is in piece-wise continuous form.

Comment: Stop guessing then, and start using solid definitions. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

$$P\left(\dfrac{1}{4}<X<1\right)=F\left(1^-\right)-F\left(\dfrac{1}{4}^{+}\right)=\dfrac{3}{4}-\dfrac{1}{16}=\dfrac{11}{16}$$

Comment: Using `\left(` and `\right)` delimiters might make formatting better.

Comment: Tnx............

Comment: $F(x)=F(x^+)$ for every $x$ and every CDF $F$.

Comment: Nope this is completely true. This also gets important specially if you have Dirac delta function in PDF.

Comment: That's why the inequalities in the question have been defined so. Also $F(x)$ $F(x^{-})$ and $F(x^+)$ are three distinct number generally and they are equal only if $F(x)$ is continuous.